# transform: translate(-50%, -50%) causing blurry text

Tags: html, css

I have a div that needs to be centered - but using

```
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Causes everything in the div to blur. I know this question has been asked a lot here, but none of the solutions (on 4 or 5 posts) have worked for me. Is there any
current solution or even another way to center the div correctly?

Comment: why don't you use a flex div and inside a margin auto

Comment: Can you please list wha options you have tried and create a code snippet.

Comment: Please provide your html. As you probably noticed, there are many ways to center something, depending on the content. So help us help you and show as exactly what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;` on the parent to center the child element.

```css
div {
 background: black;
 color: white;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>centered</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is one of the best way to bring element to center, but it needs to add position:absolute.

```
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
position:absolute;
```

then will work